# List pdf files recursively

Tags: java, list, file, recursion

I've created a tool that checks pdf files for errors. The tool selects with a filechooser a directory, checks if there are pdf files and scans them. But I want that the tool checks recursively the directory. If I try this code:

```
public class RecursiveFileDisplay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File currentDir = new File("C://Users//Tommy//Desktop"); // current directory
        displayDirectoryContents(currentDir);
    }

    public static void displayDirectoryContents(File dir) {
        try {
            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {                        
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        displayDirectoryContents(file);

                } else {
                    if (file.getName().endsWith((".pdf"))) {
                        System.out.println("     file:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

the tool will show me for each directory on a Desktop a new list and doesn't sum up all the results in one list...:
[image: 1st directorty on Desktop] [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your program to create a whole list with all the files processed, then you have to modify your `displayDirectoryContent` method as following:

```
public static List<File> displayDirectoryContents(File dir) {
    ArrayList<File> rtnFiles = new ArrayList<File>();

    try {
            File[] files = dir.listFiles();

            for (File file : files) {

                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                            rtnFiles.addAll(displayDirectoryContents(file));

                    } else {
                        if (file.getName().endsWith((".pdf"))) {
                            System.out.println("     file:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
                            rtnFiles.add(file);
                        }
                    }
            }
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return rtnFiles;
}
```

This way, it will return you with all the files found/processed. If you want this method only return you with failed files, then you will have to check not only the file is a `.pdf` file, but it is ok/failed, and then add to the list.

If you want to controll sum, then you can create a Java Class with two Integers one for pdf found files, and other for pdf failed found files. Recursively you can cum it up in the same way I build the list.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the fast help. I changed my code but the problem here again: The method of the tool to list up the pdf files is called several times; for every directory on the desktop :(

Comment: Well, maybe I don't get the point, but I believe this what it has to do, hasn't it? I mean, it is a recursive (*you ask for*) method, so in the first call it will call itself one per subdirectory and so on. Excuse me if I didn't understand you.

Comment: nono you are allright and your method is perfect! But well maybe it just didn't fit into my tool :(

Anyway thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FolderRecurs {
    public Path pathToStart = Paths.get("The_URI_OF_THE_ROOT_DIRECTORY");
    public List<File> listPDF = new ArrayList<>();
    public FolderRecurs(Path pathToStart) {
        this.pathToStart = pathToStart;
    }

    public void goRecurs() throws IOException{
        Files.walkFileTree(pathToStart, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
                //for folders
                @Override
                public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs){
                    boolean error = false;
                    //your code
                    return error?FileVisitResult.TERMINATE : FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }
                //for files
                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path filePath, BasicFileAttributes attrs){
                    boolean error = false;
                    //Convert path to file
                    File file = filePath.toFile();
                    if (file.getName().endsWith((".pdf"))){
                        listPDF.add(file);
                    }
                    //your code
                    return error?FileVisitResult.TERMINATE : FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }
        });
    }
}
```